# Changing a specific column name in pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

I was looking for an elegant way to change a specified column name in a `DataFrame`.

play data ...

```
import pandas as pd
d = {
         'one': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
         'two': [9, 8, 7, 6, 5],
         'three': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']
    }
df = pd.DataFrame(d)
```

The most elegant solution I have found so far ...

```
names = df.columns.tolist()
names[names.index('two')] = 'new_name'
df.columns = names
```

I was hoping for a simple one-liner ... this attempt failed ...

```
df.columns[df.columns.tolist().index('one')] = 'another_name'
```

Any hints gratefully received.

Answer (score 451, accepted):

A one liner does exist:

```
In [27]: df=df.rename(columns = {'two':'new_name'})

In [28]: df
Out[28]: 
  one three  new_name
0    1     a         9
1    2     b         8
2    3     c         7
3    4     d         6
4    5     e         5
```

Following is the docstring for the `rename` method.

```
Definition: df.rename(self, index=None, columns=None, copy=True, inplace=False)
Docstring:
Alter index and / or columns using input function or
functions. Function / dict values must be unique (1-to-1). Labels not
contained in a dict / Series will be left as-is.

Parameters
----------
index : dict-like or function, optional
    Transformation to apply to index values
columns : dict-like or function, optional
    Transformation to apply to column values
copy : boolean, default True
    Also copy underlying data
inplace : boolean, default False
    Whether to return a new DataFrame. If True then value of copy is
    ignored.

See also
--------
Series.rename

Returns
-------
renamed : DataFrame (new object)
```

Comment: This does not work for me unless I use the inplace=True as shown in @Jeong-Yoon Lee reply.

Answer (score 133):

Since `inplace` argument is available, you don't need to copy and assign the original data frame back to itself, but do as follows:

```
df.rename(columns={'two':'new_name'}, inplace=True)
```

Answer (score 51):

What about?

```
df.columns[2] = "new_name"
```

Comment: actually that doesn't work if later you use the column name on other operations like in df['new_name']

Comment: this answer was useful for me to change a specific column to a new name. 1st column is index 0, 2nd column is index 1, and so on. nice solution.. and i am sure this will help more people.. as the other solutions require you to know and copy the original column names beforehand.... while this is quick and dirty method.. which has its own uses.

Comment: @MasterYogurt your comment is not correct.  It is possible to perform `df['new_name']` (and other pandas things) after changing variables as outlined above.  Your comment may have been valid when it was originally posted.

Comment: That being said, using the `rename` methods is a better solution.

Comment: @JacobH I still run into this issue with Pandas v1.0.3

Answer (score 17):

If you know which column # it is (first / second / nth) then this solution posted on a similar question works regardless of whether it is named or unnamed, and in one line: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26336314/4355695

```
df.rename(columns = {list(df)[1]:'new_name'}, inplace=True)
# 1 is for second column (0,1,2..)
```

Comment: This works only if there is not "nan" in the column names, otherwise it will change all of them.

Comment: The only solution for me - I had a list of lists converted to a DF with columns 0,1,..250, and I only needed to "name" the first three columns.  This worked perfectly.

Answer (score 11):

#### Pandas 0.21 now has an axis parameter

The rename method has gained an axis parameter to match most of the rest of the pandas API.

So, in addition to this:

```
df.rename(columns = {'two':'new_name'})
```

You can do:

```
df.rename({'two':'new_name'}, axis=1)
```

or

```
df.rename({'two':'new_name'}, axis='columns')
```

Comment: df.rename({'two':'new_name'}, axis='columns')
Throws TypeError: Cannot specify both 'axis' and any of 'index' or 'columns'.

Comment: @HereHere Make sure you are on pandas version 0.21. Do `pd.__version__` to check your version

Answer (score 4):

For renaming the columns here is the simple one which will work for both `Default(0,1,2,etc;)` and existing columns but not much useful for a larger data sets(having many columns).

For a larger data set we can slice the columns that we need and apply the below code:

```
df.columns = ['new_name','new_name1','old_name']
```

Answer (score 4):

pandas version 0.23.4

```
df.rename(index=str,columns={'old_name':'new_name'},inplace=True)
```

**For the record:**

> omitting index=str will give error replace has an unexpected argument
>   'columns'

Comment: This extends nicely for more than one column: if you have a list of the `old_names` and the `new-names` (one for one), then you can do: `df.rename(columns=dict(zip(old_names, new_names)), inplace=True)`

Answer (score 3):

Following short code can help:

```
df3 = df3.rename(columns={c: c.replace(' ', '') for c in df3.columns})
```

Remove spaces from columns.

Comment: I kept getting `AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'replace'` could you expand on that.

Answer (score 2):

Another option would be to simply **copy & drop** the column:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(d)
df['new_name'] = df['two']
df = df.drop('two', axis=1)
df.head()
```

After that you get the result:

```
    one three   new_name
0   1   a       9
1   2   b       8
2   3   c       7
3   4   d       6
4   5   e       5
```

Comment: This method will not help in case the order of the columns indexes is important. The new column will be created at the end.

Answer (score 0):

```html
size = 10
df.rename(columns={df.columns[i]: someList[i] for i in range(size)}, inplace = True)
```