# Rename a single pandas DataFrame column without knowing column name

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, rename

I know I can rename single pandas.DataFrame columns with:

```py
drugInfo.rename(columns = {'col_1': 'col_1_new_name'}, inplace = True)
```

But I'd like to rename a column **based on its index** (without knowing its name) - although I know dictionaries don't have it). I would like to rename column number 1 like this:

```py
drugInfo.rename(columns = {1: 'col_1_new_name'}, inplace = True)
```

But in the DataFrame.columns dict there is no '1' entry, so no renaming is done. How could I achieve this?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Should work:

```
drugInfo.rename(columns = {list(drugInfo)[1]: 'col_1_new_name'}, inplace = True)
```

Example:

```
In [18]:

df = pd.DataFrame({'a':randn(5), 'b':randn(5), 'c':randn(5)})
df
Out[18]:
          a         b         c
0 -1.429509 -0.652116  0.515545
1  0.563148 -0.536554 -1.316155
2  1.310768 -3.041681 -0.704776
3 -1.403204  1.083727 -0.117787
4 -0.040952  0.108155 -0.092292
In [19]:

df.rename(columns={list(df)[1]:'col1_new_name'}, inplace=True)
df
Out[19]:
          a  col1_new_name         c
0 -1.429509      -0.652116  0.515545
1  0.563148      -0.536554 -1.316155
2  1.310768      -3.041681 -0.704776
3 -1.403204       1.083727 -0.117787
4 -0.040952       0.108155 -0.092292
```

It is probably more readable to index into the dataframe columns attribute:

```
df.rename(columns={df.columns[1]:'col1_new_name'}, inplace=True)
```

So for you:

```
drugInfo.rename(columns = {drugInfo.columns[1]: 'col_1_new_name'}, inplace = True)
```

Answer (score 2):

To change a column name by index, one could alter the underlying array of `df.columns` by index. So

```py
df.columns.array[1] = 'col_1_new_name'
# or
df.columns.values[1] = 'col_1_new_name'
# or 
df.columns.to_numpy()[1] = 'col_1_new_name'
```

They all perform the following transformation (without referencing `B`, it is changed):

[image: result]

However, if a new dataframe copy needs to be returned, `rename` method is the way to go (as suggested by [EdChum](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26336314/19123103)):

```py
df1 = df.rename(columns={list(df)[1]: 'col_1_new_name'})
```

If `df` has many columns, instead of `list(df)`, it might be worth it to call `islice()` from the standard `itertools` library to efficiently select a column label (e.g. the second column name):

```py
from itertools import islice
df1 = df.rename(columns={next(islice(df, 1, 2)): 'col_1_new_name'})
```